# Keeping moss balls from sticking to aquarium filter

Tags: aquarium, aquatic-plants

Not sure if aquatic plants would fall into the Pets category.

I bought some moss balls but they kept getting sucked into the filter's pipe. How can I avoid this and will this lead to any problems for the ball?

Comment: Are the balls not sinking? If you hold them underwater and squeeze them like a sponge so they pull water into them, do they sink? Or is the filter so powerful it's pulling them even though they've sunk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ball is not too small, you can force small pebbles inside it to weigh it down. As long as the pebbles are not big compared to the moss ball, the moss ball will grow around the pebbles with time.
You could also sprinkle the ball with fine sand, for a gentler approach, but the sand might fall off after a while.